# Cant Figure Out how to get Unity UI to scale correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I am trying to get a health bar to display on my UI in Unity and cannot figure out how to get the scaling to work correctly. I need the Left most value to be 0 so when currenthealth=0 the bar disappears and when currenthealth = maxhealth it should be equal to maxhealth. My current code is as follows.

```
    public RectTransform this_rect;
public float left = 3f;
public float right = 0f;
public float posY = -50f;
public float height = 20f;
public int MaxHealth = 3;
public int currentHealth = 3;
void Update()
{
    this_rect.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 1);
    this_rect.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
    Vector2 temp = new Vector2(left, posY - (height / 2f));
    this_rect.offsetMin = temp;
    temp = new Vector3(-right, temp.y + height);
    this_rect.offsetMax = temp;
   // currentHealth = (int)(left + 1 * MaxHealth);
    right = -currentHealth + MaxHealth;

}
```

Comment: why not use Slider UI element? Then no need to calculate anything, and if screen resolution changes, slider ui scales automatically too (if using proper canvas settings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a UI slider for the purpose.

> The slider component is a Selectable that controls a fill, a handle, or both. **The fill, when used, spans from the minimum value to the current value** while the handle, when used, follow the current value.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Slider.html

---

Additionally, here is a video tutorial on the UI slider which may be useful:

> UI Sliders can be used for various purposes from settings menus to health bars.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-slider